# Contol Position Not updating after moving it in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I have an application where need to dynamically create and move textblocks around in a canvas later save the layout and the load the layout.
Problem i am facing is tiring to get the position of the textblock. 
I tried this two method, but its not working

```
item.GetValue(TranslateTransform.XProperty).ToString();//always give zero
Canvas.GetTop(item);//always gives the initial position, does not update after dragging.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting coords from controls:

```
foreach (UIElement el in mapGrid.Children)
        {
            XElement control = new XElement("control");

            var ele = (HumanWorkspace)el;
            Vector v = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(el);
            double x = v.X;
            double y = v.Y;
            XAttribute atd = new XAttribute("direction", ele.Direction.ToString("d"));
            XAttribute atx = new XAttribute("x", v.X.ToString());
            XAttribute aty = new XAttribute("y", v.Y.ToString());
            control.Add(atd);
            control.Add(atx);
            control.Add(aty);
            controls.Add(control);
        }
```

Setting coords when loading state:

```
foreach (XElement ele in doc.Elements("controls"))
            {
                var con = new HumanWorkspace();
                con.Direction = (WorkspaceDirection)int.Parse(ele.Attribute("direction").Value);
                con.SetValue(TranslateTransform.XProperty, double.Parse(ele.Attribute("x").Value));
                con.SetValue(TranslateTransform.YProperty, double.Parse(ele.Attribute("y").Value));
            }
```